# How to check "autocommit" value in ActiveRecord

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, autocommit

My application is RoR and MySQL based. I would like to turn autocommit from ON to OFF and I know how to do it in MySQL. But do I need to stop and restart my Rails server to make sure this change takes effect in my application?

I would like to know if there is a way in ActiveRecord to check the value of "autocommit" in the MySQL database?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> But do I need to stop and restart my Rails server to make sure this
>   change takes effect in my application?

No, you don't have to, because that's a MySQL variable.

> I would like to know if there is a way in ActiveRecord to check the
>   value of "autocommit" in the MySQL database?

You can do:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.exec_query('SELECT @@autocommit')
```

Comment: Thanks @lunr. This does work except I had to do the following instead: `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.exec_query('SELECT @@global.autocommit')`. Looks like all global variables are under @@global. In MySQL I had to do `set @@global.autocommit=0` instead of `set @@autocommit=0`. Is there really a `@@autocommit` variable outside of `@@global`?

Answer (score 0):

how to know it is locked or not for mysql

```
show variables like '%autocommit%';
```

how to change the status for autocommit in my sql

```
set autocommit = OFF/ON;
```